# Spec explorer state numbering

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

i am new to visual studio spec explorer, need some help regarding the link image (http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC432170.gif) Can anyone explain to me how are the different states being numbered? For example, from S0 to S3 and from S3 to S9. how does the numbering work? from 3 it jumped to 9.

any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: The page from where the picture is linked from (this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee922549.aspx) indicates that `states with the same accumulator value are merged`, so more likely it's creating states for different accumulator values (starting from 0 and counting up), but only showing those that have a different accumulator values (connecting the graph to the same state via different paths), instead of showing the different states and paths separately

Answer (score 1):

Under "->Spec Explorer ->View Definitions ->New" in the Visual Studio menue you can add a new view. In this new view you can disable "ViewCollapseSteps". Now you will see much more states (15) in your graph: Also the states "S1", "S2", "S4", "S5" etc. are shown (the ones you missed).

The reason is that now every transition is split into a deterministic "call" and a non-deterministic "return"-part. This view can sometimes be useful - you can also split your rule methods like that in the model code. And now you understand also the counting of states and steps in the legend of your graph.